# SQL Server : Query Return QtyLeft from MAX StockID for ProductID

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to find the value of `QtyLeft` for a given `ProductID`. However each `ProductID` has multiple entries with unique `StockID` values. I want the `QtyLeft`, from a `ProductID` that also has the highest value `StockID`

For instance:

```
ProductID   StockID   QtyLeft
-----------------------------
   135        4564       4
   135        3456       7
   135        4958      12
   135        8848      13
```

I would like the query to return the value of 13 in the above example.

Utimately I would like to do this for 6 ProductIDs to allow the `QtyLeft` value to be displayed on a monitor displaying a lunch menu. I would like the `QtyLeft` value available for customers to see.

The below query displays the Products IDs with the highest `StockID`. However I cannot seem to work in the `Qtyleft` and then also only search for 1 of 6 ProductIDs

```
SELECT 
    MAX(StockID) AS MaxBalance, 
    ProductID 
FROM 
    [DB].[dbo].[Inventory] 
GROUP BY 
    ProductID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS
( SELECT ProductID,QtyLeft,ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY StockID Desc) rn 
FROM tab)
SELECT ProductID,QtyLeft from CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT
    ProductID, StockID, QtyLeft
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY StockID DESC)
    FROM Inventory
)AS t
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great suggestions. I went with the below, just adding AND '' to the query to display any one particuly desired result.

```
WITH CTE AS
( SELECT ProductID,QtyLeft,ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY StockID Desc) rn 
FROM tab)
SELECT ProductID,QtyLeft from CTE WHERE rn = 1 AND ProductID = '135'
```